# Unicode Characters In Oracle Command Result

Tags: c#, oracle, unicode, .net-core

I'm not sure where to post this and wondering if anyone else have experienced the bellow.

I have a C# .NetCore app that needs to get the values from an Oracle database, when the results are returned there are (unicode or special characters) suffixed to the result.

Details on System:

Oracle Library used : Mono.Data.OracleClientCore

Problem:
I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(TABLE_NAME) <= 0 THEN 'false' 
                                     ELSE 'true' 
    END AS RESULT 
FROM dba_tables 
WHERE Table_Name = '{tableName}'
```

In SQL Developer I get the following result: `false`

I'm trying to use a simple DataReader Example.

```
var existsQuery = 
                               $@"SELECT 
                                    CASE WHEN COUNT(TABLE_NAME) <= 0 
                                            THEN 'false' 
                                            ELSE 'true' END AS RESULT 
                                FROM dba_tables WHERE Table_Name = '{tableName}'";

var cmd = new OracleCommand(tableExistsQuery, this.connection);

using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
      var existResult = reader[0].ToString();
      if (existResult == "true")
            tableExistsReturn = true;
    }
}
```

When Running the given Snippet I get the following Result : `false鎍`

What I have Tried :

Converting values from ASCII to Unicode or from Unicode to ASCII.

Using Regex to replace results but this is a bad solution as the unicode or special character in question is intermediate and changes from time to time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `var existResult = reader.GetString(0)`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried .GetString. And the result is still the same. "false臇"